# How to link my site url with cname?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, cpanel

I am working on an php website,
my website url is something like
http://www.xyz.com/hosted/abc.com
I want to access the pages with above url with a cname like http://abc.xyz.com 
Means if i type http://abc.xyz.com as url it should internally serve me the pages for http://www.xyz.com/hosted/abc.com.
Please suggest,if anyone know how to achieve this ?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bind for dns server you must make a DNS zone manually and add an A record *.xyz.com. into this zone to redirect all the hosts like *.xyz.com to your web server.

Or if you use cPanel go to `Simple DNS Zone Editor` add an A Record with this name : *.xyz.com. and set Address your server's IP address.

If you use another Control Panel or DNS Server Service you have to read manual to handle requests for *.xyz.com

Then in your php code you can get the requested cname :

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$match = preg_match("([a-zA-Z0-9\-])\.xyz\.com");
$cname = $match[0];
```

Comment: You're Welcome ! Was it useful for you ?